# SharePoint Designer cannot display the item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow

User created a a list workflow using SPD 2013 and we need to edit the workflow, but we get the following error:

> SharePoint Designer cannot display the item

[image]

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this issue, we even selected the workflow, and tried to do Export to Visio and that did not work, we get the following error:

[image]

Tried the steps described in the following blog and it did not work

http://www.projectleadership.net/blogs_details.php?id=2985

Comment: Can you clean the cache and try again.Clean the cache from following folders C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SharePoint Designer\ProxyAssemblyCache
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache

Comment: not able to solve it by clearing the cache(on client machine). Any Idea??

Answer (score 1):

We found out that the Workflow was created using Nintex and that is why we were getting this error.