# SharePoint Designer cannot display the item (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I have an issue with a SharePoint 2010 workflow.

The workflow is a 2010 workflow but is held on SharePoint 2013.

Through research, I found an issue relating to workflows migrated from SharePoint 2010 or when admins have upgraded designer 2010 to 2013. This is not the case.

Here is a pic of the error;-

[image]

The workflow is still working when I create a list item.

Any ideas would be much appreciated. i.e. will this error be logged on the front end or back end and if so where?

Comment: Can you check the number of items in the list once, i guess it might have crossed 5000 due to which this error is popping up or check your permissions too. You can refer to this too - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/153905/sharepoint-designer-cannot-display-the-item

Comment: Its got about 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Solution

Somewhere along the line the file has become corrupted and SharePoint designer is not able to open it from the shortcut on the left hand navigation pane.

However if you go to;-

1. All Files
2. Workflows
3. Click the workflow name
4. Click the workflow name.xmol

[image: resolution screen shot]

You will then see the familar setting page and edit options then;-

1. Edit the workflow and save then republish.
2. Then for good measure delete the website cache by deleting all files in the below folders;-

C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache

C:\Users\your user name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

Comment: Hi, I followed the step till 4. However can't see 'Familar Setting page and edit option'.
Also clearing Cache at below folders not working.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me every once in a while. Most often deleting everything from here:

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache

And all the cache from here:

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache

And restarting SharePoint Designer, solves the problem.

Comment: This does't work. However I havn't restarted SharePoint, thats a pretty major thing in my organisation.

Comment: I meant SharePoint designer!

Comment: Hi Jurgen,
I followed these steps but no luck. The workflow was developed in SP 2010. We upgraded from 2010 to 2013 and then to 2016. Now in SPD 2013 worklows are not opening.
Am i missing some thing.

Answer (score 0):

Hello today the **problem** also occurred to me. Why I don't know yet but I found out that when I open the designer from a **HTTPS** SharePoint Site the problem occurs but **not with HTTP**. The only thing I did recently was to create an HTTPS certificate on my SharePoint WebApplication Server (SharePoint 2016) for a new WebApp. But I created the HTTPS certificate so that it is also valid for other WebApps (SAN certificate ) because I want to exchange the certificate of other WebApps too (currently I have 3 different and with the SAN certificate I would only need 1)

Comment: This does not provide an answer, once you have sufficient points you can comment anywhere.